# Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object' in angular

Tags: angular

I have just updated my angular app to angular 7 and using http client. The moment I have updated to httpClient I am getting the following error

> Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object' at line  let act =
>   data.json().find(x => x.ActivityId == activityId);

I presume the reason being get returns the type Observable. Do I need to change the return type of the method to return a response. I was under the impression that httpclient returns json by default

```
this.documentService.getDocuments(mgrStrategyId, docId, activityTypeId)
  .subscribe(data => {
    let act = data.json().find(x => x.ActivityId == activityId);
    if (act == null) {
      isOwner = false;
      InteractionDate = new Date();
    }
    else {
      isOwner = act.IsOwner;
      InteractionDate = act.InteractionDate;
    }
    this.init(mgrStrategyId, firmId, activityId, activityName, isOwner, new Date(InteractionDate), false);
  },
    err => {
      this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
    },
    () => {
    })



getDocuments(strategyId: number, documentTypeId: number, activityTypeId: number) {
  let pars = new HttpParams();
  if (strategyId != null)
    pars.set('strategyId', strategyId.toString());
  pars.set('documentTypeId', documentTypeId.toString());
  pars.set('activityTypeId', activityTypeId.toString());
  return this.http.get(this.config.api.getDocuments, { params: pars, withCredentials: true });
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, without knowin what `this.documentService.getDocuments` returns. Can you give us the type of the Observable and a sample of the data?

Comment: this is the actual return type of the get     get(url: string, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<Object>;

Comment: `console.log(data)` and what's the data output?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `data.json()` in Angular 7 `HttpClient`
 ([getting-json-data](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data)):

```
 .subscribe(data => {
   let act = data.find(x => x.ActivityId == activityId);
   if (act == null) {
    isOwner = false;
    InteractionDate = new Date();
   }
  ...
```

Comment: I had already tried the above and get error message Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: that's a compiler error. I don't know what you're returning, but to get rid of this error, you can specify `.subscribe((data: any) => ` (which is not a good idea). Or put your type of data here this.http.get<yourData[]>, `getDocuments(strategyId: number, documentTypeId: number, activityTypeId: number): Observable<yourData[]>`, `.subscribe((data: yourData[]) =>`